# How to add and display multiple markers that are parsed from a JSON object?

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

i'm trying to add and display multiple markers that are parsed from a JSON object.
in LOG i checked that all the lat long points are coming properly, but when i tried to add marker to that latlong points markers are not displaying.

this is my code

```
public class MapsEarthquakeMapActivity extends Activity {
    // Coordinates used for centering the Map
    private static final double CAMERA_LNG = 87.0;
    private static final double CAMERA_LAT = 17.0;
    // The Map Object
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private final static String URL = "xyzz";
    public static final String TAG = "MapsEarthquakeMapActivity";

    // Set up UI and get earthquake data
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new HttpGetTask().execute(URL);
    }

    private class HttpGetTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, List<EarthQuakeRec>> {
        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected List<EarthQuakeRec> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            JSONResponseHandler responseHandler = new JSONResponseHandler();
            try {
                // Get Earthquake data in JSON format
                // Parse data into a list of EarthQuakeRecs
                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ClientProtocolException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<EarthQuakeRec> result) {
            // Get Map Object
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (null != mMap) {
                // Add a marker for every earthquake

                for (EarthQuakeRec rec : result) {
                    Log.v("pointM", "" + rec.getPoint());
                    Log.v("NAMES", "" + rec.getName());
                    String point = rec.getPoint();
                    String[] latlng = point.split(",");
                    String lat = latlng[0];
                    String lng = latlng[1];
                    Double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    Double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                    Log.v("LATLNGM", "" + lat + "&" + lng);
                    // Add a new marker for this earthquake
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(lat1, lng1)).title(rec.getName()));
                }
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                        CAMERA_LAT, CAMERA_LNG)));
            }
            if (null != mClient)
                mClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is i'm getting in Log

```
03-26 08:46:21.975: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.583690&12.930022
03-26 08:46:22.067: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.585996&12.932729
03-26 08:46:22.099: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.595369&12.926995
03-26 08:46:22.139: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.592627&12.918970
03-26 08:46:22.163: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.574011&12.935930
03-26 08:46:22.187: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.564679&12.927071
03-26 08:46:22.203: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.570388&12.946059
03-26 08:46:22.203: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.580569&12.956148
03-26 08:46:22.203: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.564076&12.908918
03-26 08:46:22.203: V/LATLNGM(5193): 77.559660&12.941591
```

Where i'm going wrong..??
Please help me.

thanking all

Comment: why not? is your map display?

Comment: ha world map is displaying.

Comment: @Simple Plan I'm  getting the world map but markers are not displaying.

Comment: wait let me check your code first

Comment: i think got bug..
when i'm converting,i think only one lat long is converting to double value..

Comment: got answer..

check my log output..Lat Longs are reversed in there.. That was the problem.
Thank you all